# Что такое "образ виртуальной машины" и что он в себя включает

Tags: vmware

Я так понял, это копия диска с ОС? И ещё такой вопрос. Например я создал виртуальную машину используя какой то уже имеющийся образ. Затем поставил на неё пару своих программ, поставил дрова на видюху. После я создал из этой машины свой собственный образ. И теперь, если я создам новую виртуальную машину, используя созданный образ(с дровами и установленными программами) то новая виртуальная машина будет точной копией предыдущей? Дрова будут работать?

Comment: Не многовато ли вопросов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну примерно так и есть.

По сути образ обычно - это архив с данными виртуальной машины на какой-то момент времени. Это ее характеристики, сколько памяти, процессора, какой диск и т.п. И копия диска с данными, имеющимися на момент создания образа (снимка).

Если вы что-то сделаете внутри виртуальной машины, а потом сохраните ее образ в каком-то формате, то да, внутри этого нового образа уже будут измененные данные. И при поднятии с этого образа вы получите идентичную копию виртуалки. А вот будет ли работать драйвер или какое-то ПО внутри - это конечно вопрос. Потому что виртуальная машина может и будет точной копией, а вот внешнее окружение (то бишь хост, где поднят гипервизор) может отличаться. И тогда что-то из этого может повлиять.

Иногда используют понятие "снимок", "snapshot", это похоже на образ, является срезом состояния виртуальной машины. Обычно хранится внутри уже рабочей виртуальной машины и служит для быстрого переключения между этими состояниями.

В некоторых случаях образ может быть не таким простым, как обычный архив. Например в системах котейниризации типа Docker такой образ получается как слоеный пирог, каждый слой содержит одно определенное состояние. И когда создают на основе одного образа другой, все одинаковые слои просто используются, создаются только новые. Как то так.

Answer (score 1):

**Что такое "образ виртуальной машины"?** - Виртуальная машина (ВМ или VM) — это виртуальный компьютер, который использует выделенные ресурсы реального компьютера (процессор, диск, адаптер). Образ ВМ - это компьютерный файл, который загрузив на станцию получите Виртуальную Машину.

**Я так понял, это копия диска с ОС?** - нет не только. Это образ машины, настройки память устройства ....

**Если я создам новую виртуальную машину, используя созданный образ(с дровами и установленными программами) то новая виртуальная машина будет точной копией предыдущей?** - так задумано. Смотрите ниже для чего оно вообще.

**Дрова будут работать?** - в идеале должны. Но не сказать что всегда без проблем.

Но вы должны загрузить образ на станцию, версия и прочие у которых совместимы.

Там вырезку [отсюда](https://www.reg.ru/support/vydelennyye-servery-i-dts/virtualnyj-datatsentr-vmware/sozdanie-i-nastrojka-virtualnyh-mashin/chto-takoe-virtualnaja-mashina)

> **Для чего нужна виртуальная машина:**
>
> - чтобы разворачивать две и более независимые операционные системы на одном физическом устройстве. Например, на вашем компьютере установлена
>   операционная система Windows 7, а на виртуальную машину вы установили
>   Windows XP/8/10 или Linux;
> - для экспериментов с программным обеспечением (например, кодом, предназначенным для запуска в различных ОС), не подвергая риску
>   стабильность компьютера;
> - чтобы устанавливать и тестировать различные программы и утилиты, не занимая место на основном ПК;
> - чтобы запускать программы, которые не поддерживает основная ОС, или подключать оборудование, несовместимое с ней. Например, применять
>   Windows-программы на Mac или Linux;
> - для безопасного запуска приложения (программы), которое вызывает недоверие или подозрение на вирусы;
> - чтобы эмулировать компьютерные сети и сложные среды, не настраивая виртуальную машину каждый раз. Можно сохранить настройки и продолжить
>   с того этапа, где остановились; для создания резервных копий ОС.